# User roles are changing automatically

Tags: user-roles

I am facing a strange issue.
Some of my user roles are changing automatically.
I searched in the whole project and cannot find the location from where user roles are changing. So I added the following code in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles ){
    mail('xxxxxxx@xxxx.com','User role is changed from admin',
         'This mail is sending from set_user_role hook in functions line 2450. The user id is '.$user_id.
         'The loggedin user is '.get_current_user_id()
         );
}, 10, 3 );
```

I am getting the emails with changed userids. but the currently logged in user is showing as 0. So I assume the function is not calling from admin and the following function is running somewhere in my function.

```
$user->add_role( 'userrole' );
```

But I cannot find the function `$user->add_role();` in my project. Is this hook is called in any other cases?
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch with the action, catching the instance.

You might be able to add a debug_backtrace() to trace it back to the calling functions, and their calling functions, to see how you actually get there.